# images are not complete in responsive mode

Tags: html, css

**I have a problem, when viewing my site from a phone the images become small in width**

[image]

they only look complete if the text below is long
the images have a dimension: 70px x 70px

[image]

code:

```html
<div class="card mg-b-20">
  <div style="padding: 8;" class="card-body">
  
  
    <div style="" class="table-responsive">
      <table style="" class="table mg-b-0 text-md-nowrap" cellspacing="5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
<th class="text-center" style="padding: 1px 5px; 1px 1px; font-size: 8px; ">
  
  
  <a style="color: inherit;" href="{{ route('subcategory-detail',['categorySlug'=>$categorySlug,'subcategorySlug'=> $subcategory->slug]) }}"> 
    
   <img style="width: 70px; height: 70px;" src="{{url($subcategory->image)}}" alt="">

    <p>{{$subcategory->name}}</p>
  
  </a>
  

</th>
@endforeach
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the images dynamically by: {{url ($ subcategory-> image)}}

How do I make them look complete?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `width: 70px;` but keep the height in the image?

Comment: yes, the height keeps it

Comment: Do the images become complete then?  Or is there still an issue?

Comment: there's still the width problem, :(

Comment: Do you have any CSS code?  I can't exactly replicate your issue with just your HTML

Comment: html: https://pastebin.com/yRfcLtVv CSS I use bootstrap

Comment: hmmm I still cant seem to replicate the issue.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/h2yro68s/ The image works perfectly fine.